# how to set two textview equal size horizontally in relative layout

Tags: android

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#b4d3d3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#5d737e"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="First" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Second" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml i want  set two textview inside relative layout equal part horzontally  but using this xml left textview  is coming only few part while  right one take much space please suggest me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: use weights....

Comment: but i am using relative layout i want to do using relative layout @MinnuKaAnae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#b4d3d3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#5d737e"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="First" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Second" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this You can achive that using `LinearLayout` just set same `Weight` to Your both `TextView` like below code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5d737e"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="First" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"        
        android:text="Second" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if You want to use `RelativeLayout` than try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#5d737e"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="First" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Second" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/footer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="#b4d3d3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#5d737e"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="First" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Second" />
```

You can set programmatically width child view like below code and manage different device size easily:

```
  private TextView hello, world;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hello = findViewById(R.id.hello);
    world = findViewById(R.id.world);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParam = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) hello.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParam.width = getDeviceWidth(MainActivity.this) * 50 / 100;
    hello.setLayoutParams(relativeParam);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamWorld = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) world.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParamWorld.width = getDeviceWidth(MainActivity.this) * 50 / 100;
    world.setLayoutParams(relativeParamWorld);
}

 public int getDeviceWidth(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#b4d3d3"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/hello"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#5d737e"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="First" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/world"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Second" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Perfect weight Concept**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5d737e"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="First" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/world"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"        
    android:text="Second" />

 </LinearLayout>
```